# How does message authentication works?

Tags: botframework

I couldn't find documentation describing the auth flow of the bot.

Could you please point me to it and/or describe it?

What I am interested is if the context that I get in TurnActivity can be trusted or not?

In other words, can I be sure that the message I received is really from the user with the given ID and email, or can an attacker spoof that message altogether and send it to my bots rest endpoint?

**Goal**

Why I am asking is that I will get users to login to a 3rd party service and associate their token to access the date in 3rd party service with user in teams that I get from message context.

The data in 3rd party service is secret so should not be possible to access for other users.

My question is when we get the REST call on our [botframework](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk) message endpoint if the context comes as part of say JWT token that the SDK verifies against Microsoft identity provider and hence cannot be faked. Or is it just a simple field in body of the call. In the second case it would be pretty easy to fake the context and then through the bot get access to protected data.

Comment: You might need to provide some more context. 

What type of bot, is this a public bot? why would you want to authenticate messages sent to a bot (reason you want to authenticate could help, for example, if you just want to check if the user is using a certain interface or are you saying you have private users who should have access to the bot?)

Are you coding with a language

Comment: Thanks @xyLuz, very good points I updated the text. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: You should find the answers you are looking for in the following SDK docs: [Azure Bot Service encryption for data at rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-encryption?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Bot Framework authentication basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), and [Direct Line enhanced authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-security-enhanced?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).